# What's the difference between Anti-Corruption Layer and Adapters?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design, adapter

Even thought there was a good answer [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184464/what-is-an-anti-corruption-layer-and-how-is-it-used), the explanation is still a bit confusing me.

I do not see any huge differences between Anti-Corruption layer and Adapters and the only difference that I see is the difference in the definitions that Anti Corruption Layer is a kind of wrapper that allows you to isolate your domain from the corruption of someone else's domain.

But in [another article](https://medium.com/solutions-architecture-patterns/anti-corruption-layer-pattern-bd75e1f2be7f), the Anti Corruption Layer is generally acting as Adapter.

Let's take an example. I have a library that allows me to query MongoDB from code, developed by the official MongoDB developers for my programming language. I also have a user domain model (let's name it `User`). The User has a unique UserID, which must match the ID in MongoDB. The library for MongoDB uses the `primitive.ObjectID` type for identifiers. Because I don't want to refer to the types for the database from the domain model, I create a separate type `Identifier`, which, in fact, is a regular string. Thus, in the domain model, UserID will be of type `Identifier`, and `primitive.ObjectID` itself will be converted to `Identifier` during mapping by conversion to a string.

Question: in this case, is `Identifier` an anti-corruption layer? Do you have any examples that can most accurately show me the difference between the anti-corruption layer and the adapter pattern?

I have read the following articles: [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/anti-corruption-layer), [2](https://medium.com/solutions-architecture-patterns/anti-corruption-layer-pattern-bd75e1f2be7f), [3](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184464/what-is-an-anti-corruption-layer-and-how-is-it-used) but none of them I find useful.

Answer (score 1):

### Anti Corruption Layer

#### is consist of

- **Adapter**: It adapts one interface to another
- **Facade**: An interface between callers and targets
- **Translator**: It converts one data structure to another

#### data flow from Legacy to New

1. The adapter knows how should the legacy system invoke methods on the facade
2. The facade knows how to map legacy system's requests to new system's requests
3. The translator knows how to convert legacy system's entities to new system's entities

#### data flow from New to Legacy

1. The adapter knows how should the new system invoke methods on the facade
2. The facade knows how to map new system's responses to legacy system's responses
3. The translator knows how to convert new system's entities to legacy system's entities

---

As you can see the flow is exactly the same. You can think of the components like this:

- Adapter maps the system X workflow to system Y
- Facade maps individual system X methods to system Y
- Translator maps parameters and return types from system X to system Y and vice-versa

Because these components are tend to be used together, sometimes all of these are smashed into a single component and it is usually named (*badly*) as an adapter. IMHO it is a better approach to have smaller, more focused components.